# JQTouch on Android 2.2 has issue with TextField

Tags: android, jqtouch

We have built a Android application using JQTouch. The GUI is built with HTML and javascript.
We just found that there is an issue with runing our app on Android 2.2

The textfield doesn't respond well with touch selection, wherease this problem doesn't happen on 1.5 Android Device.

I suspect that the problem is caused by **jqtouch.css**, becase if I disable importing for jqtouch.css, the textfield respond very well.

I am just wondering if somebody came accross with the same problem. or is there any solution to this problem, becase I know nothing about web programming (css) and don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Having the same issue. Would love some feedback.